# Not able to access network drive from VB.NET Windows Service

Tags: windows, service

I have a Windows service developed in VB.NET. This Windows service picks a file every night at 8 PM from copies a file from my `C:\ftpDocs` to `Y:\FtpDocs` folder.

`Y:` is a mapped drive which is `\\sourceServer\Output files`. When I run the same code from a VB.NET Windows application instead of a Windows service it is working absolutely fine. But from the service it is throwing access denied error accessing `\\sourceServer\Output`.

It seems the Windows service runs from `C:\windows\system32`. For this reason I tried changing the current directory to `C:\ftpService` (This is the folder where my application is).

To access the mapped drive I provide a userid and password which is not my Windows userid and password. Do you think this is the reason why it is not able to access it from the Windows service?

If yes, how is it working from Windows application? This issue is not going away for the past one month now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What drives are currently mapped is maintained per user -- it'd be a big no-no for me to be able to access files on a share on which you have credentials just because we're both logged on at the same time.

Your service will need to map the share itself using saved credentials of some kind (you could hard code them, if you like, though that's not terribly secure and represents a maintainability burden besides).  A good example of how to do this is [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357/) -- though, I haven't used this code, I've just read the article.

Comment: Thanks Dathan, I will surely try this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Typically a Windows service runs under an id whose credentials are not authorized to access files on the network.  Try running your windows service under the domain account which can access the network files.  Make sure that this account has access to both the network and local folders/files that it will be reading and writing.

Also, you'll want to use the UNC path, not a mapped drive.  The mapped drive won't be mounted for the service.

Comment: tvanfosson,
I tried UNC Path too. But it didn't help. Next thing is I am planning to get my NetworkID added to the mapped drive folder.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but it's worth noting that you should NEVER run a service using a users credentials - What if the user quits and you disable their account? When I started at one job, I was shown and old dev's computer. He'd left a few years previously. His account was active and his PC was kept on 24/7. Hundreds of business critical processes relied on his machine/creds - They couldn't even change the password because it was hard coded all over the place. Needless to say, I left rapidly.

Comment: Personally, I use one account per application - A domain acct. for services which use the network or server-specific ones otherwise. SQL is `Server\SQLService` and Sophos AV is `Domain\SophosService`. You should make sure normal users cannot log on as those accounts (on the DC/Server). After that, you can grant permissions to shares/other resources for specific apps.

Comment: @Basic - I agree.  A separate "service" account is the way to go.